# Fit ARIMA model

Tags: r, zoo

I have a zoo time series object, `vels`:

```
2011-05-01 00:00:00 7.52
2011-05-01 00:10:00 7.69
2011-05-01 00:20:00 7.67
2011-05-01 00:30:00 7.52
2011-05-01 00:40:00 7.38
2011-05-01 00:50:00 7.56
2011-05-01 01:00:00 7.41
2011-05-01 01:10:00 7.11
2011-05-01 01:20:00 7.23
2011-05-01 01:30:00 7.31
```

I would like to fit an Arima model but I don't know how to find the orders automatically.

PS: I have read that I must use `arima.sim` but I think you have to enter orders too in that function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need `arima.sim()`, which is for simulating from a specified ARIMA model, not estimating the parameters of one.

See the `auto.arima()` function in package **forecast**. The package web page on CRAN is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html). You will need to coerce your `"zoo"` object to a `"ts"` classed object via the `as.ts()` method provided in the **zoo** package, as that is what the underlying fitting function `arima()` expects to be provided with.

The example from `?auto.arima` is:

```
> fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
> fit
Series: WWWusage 
ARIMA(1,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1
      0.6504  0.5256
s.e.  0.0842  0.0896

sigma^2 estimated as 9.793:  log likelihood=-254.15
AIC=514.3   AICc=514.55   BIC=522.08
```

with `fit` now containing the chosen order. Model diagnostics can then be produced, e.g. via `tsdiag(fit)`:

[image: tsdiag output]

And the time series plus n-ahead forecasts for the next 20 observations produced via `plot(forecast(fit, h = 20))`:

[image: forecast(fit, h = 20) output]

Comment: The p-values for the Ljung-Box test given by tsdiag are wrong, as it does not correct for lost degrees of freedom p+q. [see here](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm)

Comment: I think it fair to say that not everyone agrees with everything on that page. I am not in a position to comment with any authority however on the p-values.

Comment: Gavin, on what basis is it "fair to say that not everyone agrees with everything on that page"?

Comment: @NathanGould The author(s) of the function(s) in question has/have seen the bug "report" and has/have done nothing to change the code. You can search the R mailing lists archives for postings by one of the authors (of the book to which that site refers) if you want to follow more.